# Frequency of the positions of strings in R

Tags: r

I wish to count the position of each factor in the following dataset:

```
df <-data.frame(fact=c("a,b", "c,b"))
```

So, my ideal output is something like that:

```
  Factor   position1      Position2

  a          1            0
  b          0            2
  c          1            0
```

For instance `b` occurred two times in the second position.

What I have tried is very tedious, I separate the  string to columns and than measure the frequency of each of them one by one:

```
library(splitstackshape)

df <-cSplit(df,"fact", ",")

table(df$fact_2)
```

I am wondering if there is any tips that make my work easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `cSplit` gives a `data.table` as a result, you can melt and cast to get a result in a simpler fashion:

```
dfspl <-cSplit(df,"fact", ",")

dcast(melt(dfspl, measure.vars=names(dfspl)), value ~ variable, fun.agg=length)

#   value fact_1 fact_2
#1:     a      1      0
#2:     b      0      2
#3:     c      1      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option from `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)      
separate(df, fact, into = c("position1", "position2")) %>% #splits the column into two
        gather()  %>% #converts to long format
        group_by(key, value) %>% #grouped by both the columns
        count() %>% #get the count
        spread(key, n, fill=0) #spread to wide format
# A tibble: 3 × 3
#  value position1 position2
#* <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     a         1         0
#2     b         0         2
#3     c         1         0
```